# Closed form for $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sin(x)+\cos(x)} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

I'm solving an integral in three coordinates. One of the coordinates is the integral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sin(x)+\cos(x)} dx$.

Is possible to get a closed form for that?

My efforts.

Let $u=-x$.

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sin(x)+\cos(x)} dx =-\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4-u)} du $

Comment: $2\pi I_0(\sqrt{2})$, where $I_0$ is a modified Besselfunction. I think that is as close as you will get. Is that closed enough?

Comment: Great. I will check. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\,dx.
$$
From the [trigonometric addition formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) $\cos(\alpha-\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\sin\beta$, with $\alpha=\pi/4, \beta=x$, using the [special value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals#Table_of_some_common_angles) $\cos(\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4) = 1/\sqrt2$, we have
$$
\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \sqrt2\cos\left(\pi/4-x\right).
$$
From here we have
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sqrt2\cos\left(\pi/4-x\right)}\,dx\\
 &= \int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sqrt2\cos\left(x\right)}\,dx \tag{1}\\
 &= \int_0^{\pi}e^{\sqrt2\cos\left(x\right)}\,dx + \int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{\sqrt2\cos\left(x\right)}\,dx \tag{2}\\
 &= \int_0^{\pi}e^{\sqrt2\cos\left(x\right)}\,dx + \int_0^{\pi}e^{-\sqrt2\cos\left(x\right)}\,dx. \tag{3}\\
\end{align}
In $(1)$ we used the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) $x\mapsto\pi/4-x$ and the [periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) of the integrand. In $(2)$ we used the [additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Properties) of integration on intervals. In $(3)$ for the second integral we used the substitution $x \mapsto x-\pi$, and the [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Symmetry.2C_shifts.2C_and_periodicity) of the cosine function, $\cos(x-\pi) = -\cos(x)$.

Using the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and the [properties](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/07/01/01/) of the modified Bessel function of the first kind, we have
$$
I_0(z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{z\cos(t)} \,dt = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{-z\cos(t)} \,dt.
$$
Putting all this together, we have
$$
I = 2\pi I_0\left(\sqrt2\right).
$$